# Symfony Doctrine - adding JOIN to the same relation twice with different conditions

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

Hi I have two entities:

- Topic
- Topic_status

In the first one I store all topics which has for example content, author, date, etc.

In the second one I store information about like/dislike of topic for every logged in user.

I want to show on the page in one moment information about individual 
*like* status of the user who is logged in, and also a list of all statuses for this topic from every other user.

The first issue is easy because I can add `LEFT JOIN` to Topic, and add `Topic_status WITH user = logged.in.user`

But then I have only information about the logged-in user (1 result) and can't get list of all statuses for this topic.

I've tried something like this:

```
query = $em ->createQuery('
    SELECT t, ts, tsall FROM My\Bundle\Entity\Topic  t 
    LEFT JOIN t.topicStatuses ts WITH tp.author = '.$loggedInUserId.'
    LEFT JOIN t.topicStatuses tsall
');
$topics = $query->getResult();
```

I've tried to use `LEFT JOIN` twice, naming them differently like `ts` and `tsall` because I want two different results from the same related entity.

When I use this code there are no errors, but still I have no idea how to get results for one and then results for the other one.

In Twig I work on returned object Topics like :

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    {% for status in topic.topicStatuses %}
        (here I get only one result from first LEFT JOIN)
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to get results from the same related entity using second `LEFT JOIN`? If yes, please explain to me how.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating the situation and should just use two queries.

Comment: When you join entites like this, it can confuse Doctrine what to load to topic as status, if you want everything in one result, have a look at [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#fetching-multiple-from-entities).

Comment: Jason Roman maybe you are right, but I need one query to work with twig loop, If I would have two queries then I have no idea how to use them in one loop because there is no relation beetwen those objects